# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Facebook' not found

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

I can see this has been asked a few times but after trying the solutions none seem to do the trick. All I want to do is pull in the member count of one of my facebook groups. I installed the SDK with composer (I'm local using XAMPP) so my directory now has /vendor/ and within this /autoload.php and 2 folders 'composer and 'facebook'.

My understanding was if I require_once autoload.php any other dependencies are automatically included through that but my error is **Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Facebook' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\fbook\count.php:9 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\fbook\count.php on line 9**

So it's clear it is looking for the class 'Facebook' within my page but I can't see why.

One solution in another thread was to add

```
use Facebook/Facebook;
```

to the top but I then get **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '/', expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\fbook\count.php on line 2**

**EDIT:** After correcting the backslash in the 'use' part (full code updated) I now get **Fatal error: Uncaught Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException: Required "app_id" key not supplied in config and could not find fallback environment variable "FACEBOOK_APP_ID" in C:\xampp\htdocs\fbook\vendor\facebook\graph-sdk\src\Facebook\Facebook.php:139 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\fbook\count.php(10): Facebook\Facebook->__construct(Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\fbook\vendor\facebook\graph-sdk\src\Facebook\Facebook.php on line 139**

Is this a DUH monent where I should be adding the app details to a config file (as I haven't and can't see one!)

My App Id, Secret and Group ID are correct. Could anyone please advise what needs tweaking? Full code is below.

```
<?php
    use Facebook\Facebook;
    require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

      $config = array(
        'app_id' => 'MY_APP_ID',
        'app_secret' => 'MY_SECRET',
        'cookie' => true
      );
      $facebook = new Facebook($config);
      $query = urlencode("SELECT uid FROM group_member WHERE gid = 0groupidhere0");
      try {
        $fbData = $facebook->api("/fql?q={$query}");
        $member_count =  count($fbData['data']);
      } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {};
?>

<div><?php echo $member_count; ?></div>
```

Comment: `use Facebook/Facebook;` This should be a backslash: `use Facebook\Facebook;`

Comment: @AlexHowansky I've updated that but now get a much scarier error.

Comment: _'Required "app_id" key not supplied'_ You called it `appId`.

Comment: @AlexHowansky Corrected (secret should have been app_secret too so corrected also) My error now is Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Facebook\Facebook::api() in C:\xampp\htdocs\fbook\count.php:13 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\fbook\count.php on line 13 which relates to

Comment: $fbData = $facebook->api("/fql?q={$query}");

Comment: `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: @MaikLowrey Tried that, no change, Checking the SDK docs now in case I'm using older code that needs to be slightly different for the latest version.

Comment: Definitely must be that I am using older code but the latest SDK, scouring all the docs but struggling to find what it needs to be though.

Comment: I don't know, all I can say is I'm continuing reading through the docs in the hope someone may pop in and see where I'm going wrong but my guess here is my code must be for an older version however the docs for the latest version don't mention this, perhaps this type of query ie. member count is no longer supported? I can't see one way or the other.

Comment: FQL has been removed ages ago. You need to start with https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v12.0/group And it might help if you used Graph API Explorer to figure out what the request needs to look like to be successful, before you starting writing code yourself. At least that makes it easier to figure out whether you have an issue with the API syntax itself, or with using the SDK.